# algorithm related to dyadic decomposition

Tags: arithmetic, recursive-algorithms

Starting from an integer $n >0$, iterate the two operations of
substracting one and dividing by $2$ (when the number is even) until
$1$ is reached. Thus when the number is odd we can only substract $1$,
but when the number is even we may apply either of the two operations.
Denote by $f(n)$ the minimal number of steps needed
to reach $1$ from $n$. Thus $f(1)=0$ and

$$
f(n)=\left\lbrace 
\begin{array}{lcl}
1+{\textsf{min}}(f(m),f(2m-1)), &\text{when}& n \text{ is even}, n=2m,\\
1+f(n-1)  &\text{when}& n \text{ is odd}.
\end{array}\right. \tag{1}
$$

The natural, “greedy” way to proceed is to always divide by $2$ when the number is 
even and substract $1$ otherwise. 
I have checked up to $n=10^6$ that this "greedy" strategy is the unique optimal
solution ; in other words, we always have $f(m)<f(2m-1)$ for $m>1$ in the first
line of $(1)$. In fact, it seems that if we decompose $m$ as $2^i(2j+1)$ where
$i$ and $j$ are nonnegative integers, then

$$
f(2m-1)-f(m)=\left\lbrace 
\begin{array}{lcl}
i &\text{when}& j=0,\\
i+1  &\text{when}& j>0.
\end{array}\right. \tag{2}
$$

Although my impression is that there is probably a simple way to show (2)
by induction, and perhaps a simple interpretation of $f(n)$ in the vein of
“the number of ones in the dyadic decomposition on $n$”, I was unable to find it.
Any ideas? Is this perhaps already known ?